# Find and Replace loop in pandas for Sub string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and alot of the values in one of the columns have python-unfriendly characters, like &.

I wanted to make a dictionary and then loop through with find and replacements

sort of like this:

```
replacements = {
    " ": ""
    ,"&": "and"
    ,"/":""
    ,"+":"plus"
    ,"(":""
    ,")":""
    }

df['VariableName']=df['VariableName'].replace(replacements,regex=True)
```

however this brings up the following error code:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need escape special regex characters in dictionary comprehension:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'VariableName':['ss dd +','(aa)']})

replacements = {re.escape(k):v for k, v in replacements.items()}
df['VariableName']=df['VariableName'].replace(replacements,regex=True)

print (df)
  VariableName
0     ssddplus
1           aa
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. I'll accept answer once the timer lets me. Thanks alot